# My Application won't start up?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, constructor, android-lifecycle

I'm not really sure why my application won't start up, I get no errors and I have no idea what's going on? I'm pretty new to android and this is just a basic calculator, but it keeps crashing every time I start it up.

***************Main Activity.java**********************

```
package com.example.alex.myapplication;


         import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     new Something(this);

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
    }
```

*******************Something.java******************

```
package com.example.alex.myapplication;


   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Button;




   public class Something extends Activity {


  private Button add,subtract,multiply,devide;
  private EditText editA, editB, editC;
  private double doubleA,doubleB,doubleC;

        public Something(Activity a) {

           click();


      }


       public void click(){
           editA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
           editB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
           editC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
          doubleA =Double.parseDouble(editA.getText().toString());
          doubleB =Double.parseDouble(editB.getText().toString());


              add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
              subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract);
              multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
              devide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devide);

               add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                     doubleC = doubleA+doubleB;
                     String s = "" + doubleC;
                      editC.setText(s);


                   }
               });

               subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA-doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });

               multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA*doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



           devide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA/doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



       }



   }
```

******************activity_main.xml****************

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
      >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/idk"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="5"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="First number"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="5"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:hint="Second number"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="166dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Subtract"
    android:id="@+id/subtract"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/multiply"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/add" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Multiply"
    android:id="@+id/multiply"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/devide"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/devide"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/devide" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Devide"
    android:id="@+id/devide"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:hint="Results"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />


           </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Include the full stack trace from logcat.  We aren't going to go through a program line by line and guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have created a constructor for the `Something` class

```
public Something(Activity a) {

       click();

}
```

instead of using `onCreate()` is probably the source of the error.

`Something` is derived from `Activity`, in which you *have* to override `onCreate()` at the very least, and set the `View` of your `Activity` in it. You haven't done that, and instead you have created a constructor for `Something` which is also not allowed.

The solution to your problem is to replace the constructor with `onCreate()` and set the `View` of that `Activity` using `setContentView()`. Also, you cannot create an `Activity` object using

```
new Something(this);
```

Comment: I gave you an up vote. Oh, I didn't want to make a new "Activity" all I wanted to do is use "Something.java" to HANDLE the "onClick" methods so that it would calculate the numbers. You know like have "MainActivity" be the "Activity" and "Something.java" handle the events. I'm not sure why it doesn't work here since it worked fine in java.

Comment: I believe you were looking for an [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to set on a `Button` or `ListView`.

Comment: Yup I did all of that, but you know how in java you have separate classes for the "Gui" and then then other classes that handle other stuff. Well how do I do this in android, like my "MainActivity" is my "Gui" and my "Something.java" class handles the "onClicksListeners" so why isn't it executing the "Something.java" in my "onCreate" method? I mean am I doing it wrong, I'm just really confused.