# My java class won't run inside main activity?

Tags: java, android

Ok so I fixed whatever was wrong with my application on why it wasn't starting but now my MainActivity won't execute my java class in which I have the methods that does the calculation for my simply calculator. I'm pretty new to android and I with plain java if you run a class in "main" it executes that class so I'm not really sure what's going on, when I click a button the calculation that's suppose to take place in my "something.java" class doesn't happen so I'm not sure if my "MainActivity" is executing my "something.java" class. Here's my code from another question I asked(code works, just had to restart IDE): [My Application won't start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353918/my-application-wont-start-up)

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: @PM77-1 That is my current code, it was a problem with my IDE, I re-synched and restarted it and it worked.

Comment: Even though that is your current code you should include it here for simplicity's sake and longevity. You may one day delete that one and maroon this one.

Comment: Did you actually read the **accepted** answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your other post and that is not how you start an Activity. you are trying to create an instance of Activity like how you would a normal object. While this is acceptable in java, it does not work this way in Android.

Android is based on callbacks. An activity represents a screen on the device. It is started using Intents. You need to specify the layout that the activity will use in it's screen and you typically do this in your onCreate() method. Your Something.java is an Activity which has no layout and no onCreate() method. I would suggest reading up on Activity lifecycles and inflating layouts in Android before continuing.

You can start Something.java from ActivityA like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Something.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Using intents is how you start an Activity. Inside Something.java, you need to override the onCreate() method just as you have done in your first Activity and then set the view for it.

Like I said, Android is based on method callbacks. While you are still working with Java, you are expected to follow a pattern to interact with the Android OS.

Comment: @Sunii The thing I thought that since I made an instance of "Something.java" in my "onCreate" method in my "MainActivity" class WHICH has a layout specified shouldn't it work? Basically what I wanted to accomplish is have my layout specified in my "MainActivity" class and have the calculations in my "Something.java" class, but when I click a button which in my "Something.java" class is suppose to handle the "onClick" it doesn't do anything. I made an instance of "something" in the "onCreate" method and it has a layout so why won't it work.

Comment: No, Something.java is a separate activity. Each Activity should have it's own layout (you can reuse layouts but that will break the design paradigm). See my edited answer on how to start an Activity.

Comment: Oh, I didn't want to make a new "Activity" all I wanted to do is use "Something.java" to HANDLE the "onClick" methods so that it would calculate the numbers. You know like have "MainActivity" be the "Activity" and "Something.java" handle the events. I'm not sure why it doesn't work here since it worked fine in java.

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you mean. But nope, Android doesn't allow you to use the onClickListener() in one Context (an Activity is a Context) inside of another. Each Activity will have to implement it's own onClickListener(). the reason is since an Activity represents a different screen with a different task to perform, you cannot use the onClick() method from a different activity.

Comment: Ok, any idea on how to use onClick() from my something.java class without having to make it an activity? the problem is if I don't make it an activity I won't be able to use the findViewById method to assign the buttons in my layout.xml a button listener?